# Hosting Asp.net MVC 2 application on Windows Server 2008 Gives 500 Error

Tags: iis, asp.net

I am trying to host my ASP.net MVC2 application on MS Server 2008. When I attempt to view the website it returns a 500.19 internal server error. The error message claims that there is a duplicate section defined.

> Config Error There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined

This section does not even exist in the application's web.config.

The physical location of my website is c:\TestPortal but the error appears to be complaining about a web.config file that is not even related to this application

> Config File \?\C:\UriAbstraction\web.config

I have created an Application under the 'Default Web Site' and the physical location is correctly set.

Why is iis given me this error when I am visiting my application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have .NET 4.0 installed, right?

"The workaround for the second scenario is to delete or comment out all the system.web.extensions configuration section definitions and configuration section group definitions from the application-level Web.config file. These definitions are usually at the top of the application-level Web.config file and can be identified by the configSections element and its children."

source:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1571308.aspx/1

and
http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes